# Meteor Step by Step my first app guide?

Tags: meteor

Has anyone seen or produced a step by step `Meteor.js` guide?

I'm not too familiar with `Javascript` but I know `HTML` and `CSS` and I'm curious how to get started messing around with `Meteor.js`, see how it works and what I can make with it.

I'm not sure how to edit the code thats found in the examples so I thought maybe I should ask here and see if there is any helpful links that you all could point me too.

Comment: Consider starting with JavaScript itself, then moving to newer things like Meteor.

Comment: http://www.eventedmind.com/ It can also help you.

Comment: The following Quora post has a very good collection:
http://www.quora.com/Meteor-web-framework/Where-can-good-Meteor-tutorials-be-found-other-than-the-official-ones

Answer (score 9):

Meteor is still pretty new at the moment. There is no official guide, except the [screencast](http://www.meteor.com/screencast) wich is more like a demo.
You still can browse the [source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor), but without understanding javascript enough, you will have to wait a little bit.

[Meteor examples](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples) are very self explanatory, if you still want to get in now, read the code and try to understand by your self.

Comment: Can't add answers because the question was abusively closed. There are many tutorials in the meantime. Quora has a good list at http://www.quora.com/Meteor-web-framework/Where-can-good-Meteor-tutorials-be-found-other-than-the-official-ones

Answer (score 6):

Thomas Lomas has just made an great tutorial screencast: http://vimeo.com/40300075

Answer (score 1):

The meteor examples are very self explanatory to anyone a bit familiar with JavaScript and node.js, so you should start learning that first. A good place to start is http://www.nodebeginner.org/

Comment: Downvoting this...he asked for meteor guide, not nodejs, althought it'd be beneficial to learn that as well.

Comment: Upvoting. Node.js skills will be useful for the OP.